# Soundcloud: Getting all users who contributed a song to a group

Tags: python, soundcloud

Whats the best way to get ALL users who contributed a song to a group? I'm working with Python, is there any curl url which can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the [soundcloud API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists) sounds like a good place to start. From what I understand you want the following URL

```
GET /groups/{id}/contributors | list of users who contributed a track to the group
```

While you can use urllib or cURL for this task, I highly recommend using the python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library which will simplify any of the requests. The actual python requests code you will probably end up using will look something like this

```
import requests
group_id = '' # FILL IN THE GROUP ID 
client_id = '' # FILL IN THE CLIENT ID
r = requests.get('https://api.soundcloud.com/groups/%s/contributors?client_id=%s' %(group_id, client_id))
```

And then the variable `r` would contain the response from the server.

Comment: Thanks, this is working great but I'm just getting 200 users at a time... And I want the others too. So I tried to use the offset parameter but I'm not getting the same users for each offset...